# Laravel query builder bypasses database view clauses

Tags: php, database, laravel, oracle, oci8

I am using [Yajra/Oci8 Oracle DB driver for laravel](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8) at some point I notice, when I select on a specific view it returns a different result from what I should be getting.

**Query and Result from oracle Sqldeveloper 270 records**

[image]

**Query and Result from Laravel no query builder Returns 270 records**

[image]

**Query and Result from Laravel using Query Builder Returns 5613 records**

[image]

Please help.. I've already tested it into other machines even on our production server, still no idea what has gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that the NLS date format of the oracle database that I was trying to query into is not the same with the default NLS date format that **Yajra/laravel Oci8 Oracle Drive** initialized, so I have to alter the `$sessionvars` to make it right.

Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Use this query

```
DB::table('table_name')->get();
```

Comment: It is similar to what I did. I just specified the connection because my application uses three therefore i did `DB::connection('oracle')->('table_name')->get();` give's me the wrong result.